# How do you specify a join table's name and columns in a Grails 4 domain class?

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm currently upgrading a Grails 4.0.1 application to Grails 4.0.11 and I'm running into an issue with the join tables for one of my domain classes.

My `Account` class has multiple `hasMany` relationships with my class `CompletionStatus`:

```
import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic
import grails.gorm.hibernate.mapping.MappingBuilder

@GrailsCompileStatic
class Account {

    String name

    static hasMany = [successCompletionStatuses: CompletionStatus, noShowCompletionStatuses: CompletionStatus,
            partialSegmentAttendanceCompletionStatuses: CompletionStatus]

    // Have distinct join tables for the CompletionStatus associations
    // https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10811#issuecomment-337931115
    static mapping = MappingBuilder.orm {
        property('successCompletionStatuses') {
            joinTable { name "account_success_completion_statuses" }
        }
        property('noShowCompletionStatuses') {
            joinTable { name "account_no_show_completion_statuses" }
        }
        property('partialSegmentAttendanceCompletionStatuses') {
            joinTable {
                name "account_partial_completion_statuses"
                key {
                    name "account_partial_completion_statuses_id"
                }
                column {
                    name "different_completion_status_id"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static constraints = {
        name blank: false
    }
}
```

```
import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic

@GrailsCompileStatic
class CompletionStatus {

    String courseType
    String status

    static constraints = {
        courseType nullable: true
        status blank: false
    }
}
```

The mapping in `Account` works as expected in Grails 4.0.1, with multiple join tables being created in the database. However, when running the application in Grails 4.0.11 I get an error at startup which I eventually discovered can be prevented by removing the multiple hasMany relationships from `Account`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getCanonicalName(Column.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.getColumn(Table.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.addColumn(Table.java:257)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindSimpleValue(GrailsDomainBinder.java:2938)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(GrailsDomainBinder.java:450)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder$GrailsCollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(GrailsDomainBinder.java:3406)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1693)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1661)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.java:287)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:86)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:39)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:23)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:64)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:52)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.ConnectionSourcesInitializer.create(ConnectionSourcesInitializer.groovy:24)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.<init>(HibernateDatastore.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor64.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:175)
    ... 123 common frames omitted
```

I found I was able to get the database tables `account_success_completion_statuses` and `account_no_show_completion_statuses` created by specifying the mapping in `Acccount` like so, but I am still unable to customize the table name and column names for `account_partial_completion_statuses`:

```
static mapping = MappingBuilder.orm {
    property('successCompletionStatuses') {
        joinTable "account_success_completion_statuses"
    }
    property('noShowCompletionStatuses') {
        joinTable "account_no_show_completion_statuses"
    }
    property('partialSegmentAttendanceCompletionStatuses') {
        joinTable {
            name "account_partial_completion_statuses"
            key "account_partial_completion_statuses_id"
            // This isn't setting the column name
            column "different_completion_status_id"
            // This isn't setting the column name either
            // column { name "different_completion_status_id" }
        }
    }
}
```

With the mapping above, a database table named `account_completion_status` is created instead of `account_partial_completion_statuses`, and it has columns `account_partial_completion_statuses_id` and `completion_status_id`.

For more context in case it is needed, I'm using MySQL 5.6.51 and the library `mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.48` in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the [Grails documentation on joinTable](https://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Database%20Mapping/joinTable.html)!

The join tables are created properly in the database and the application runs fine when I specify my `Account` class like so:

```
import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic

@GrailsCompileStatic
class Account {

    String name

    static hasMany = [successCompletionStatuses: CompletionStatus,
            noShowCompletionStatuses: CompletionStatus,
            partialSegmentAttendanceCompletionStatuses: CompletionStatus]

    // Have distinct join tables for the CompletionStatus associations
    // https://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Database%20Mapping/joinTable.html
    static mapping = {
        successCompletionStatuses joinTable: [
                name: 'account_success_completion_statuses']
        noShowCompletionStatuses joinTable: [
                name: 'account_no_show_completion_statuses']
        partialSegmentAttendanceCompletionStatuses joinTable: [
                name: 'account_partial_completion_statuses',
                key: 'account_partial_completion_statuses_id',
                column: 'different_completion_status_id']
    }

    static constraints = {
        name blank: false
    }
}
```